# How do I center tick labels in both for both major and minor ticks

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I'd like to label an axis based on dates with "nested" labels and ticks that mark off the beginning and end of periods: Minor ticks marking the boundaries between months, and major ticks marking the boundaries between years, with *labels for each centered within the period* — i.e., month labels between the ticks marking the month; year labels between those marking years.

With

```
 ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
 ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))(4, 8, 12)
 ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
 ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m'))

 ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', direction='out', pad=15, length=20)
 ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', direction='out', length=10)
```

and later

```
matplotlib.pyplot.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

I can get as far as

[image]

but that leaves the labels at the tick marks, rather than between them.

Are there minor changes I can make to the above code to center the labels between the corresponding ticks? The [solutions I've seen](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/centered_ticklabels.html) for centering seem to "use up" minor ticks to get centering for major ticks; but I need centering for both.

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have time to post a full answer here, but I do this by using a second pair of axes for the same subplot with coordinates of ticks set in the centres. Then I show ticks on the "old" axes and show labels, but not ticks, on the "new" ones.

Comment: You can have a look here, in my repo: https://github.com/Phlya/hicplotlib/blob/master/hicplotlib.py

In lines 404-417 I add a second pair of axes; generally, it is very easy.

Comment: @Ilya: So there's no more idiomatic (built in) way of simply labeling a ti interval (as opposed to a tick location?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way, except for the one you mentioned in the question. I might be just missing it of course.

Comment: @Phlya: I get `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'twin'` when I try `twin()` (from [line 404](https://github.com/Phlya/hicplotlib/blob/master/hicplotlib.py)), and using `twinx()` makes the axis jump to the opposite side. How do I twin "in place"?

Comment: You have to use host_subplot() for twin() to work on the axes, see the imports in the same file in the beginning. Sorry, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @Phlya: That seems like the key. Can you elaborate in an answer (esp. the use of `host_subplot()` and `twin()`). The latter seems to be critical to making things work smoothly and flexibly: multiple calls to `twinx()` and `twiny()` make axes jump back and forth and seem to make the the display of things like axes labels sensitive to the order in which they are set — e.g. after using `twinx()` to add the twin for tick labels, the axis label on my y axis vanished, and had to be moved to another axis.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to find time for that today.

Comment: Did it work for you in the end? Sorry, I am super busy all the time :(

Comment: @Phlya: I have something patched together. But I'd love to do it right (with `twin`). No rush.